# vienna RNA fold python installation issue

Tags: python, macos, python-2.7, installation

I'm having some issues installing the python wrapper for the vienna RNA package (found [here](https://www.tbi.univie.ac.at/RNA/documentation.html)). I previously had been able to install this program's python implementation by moving the compiled python scripts into my pythonpath (the program doesn't seem to want to do it no matter what I do). However, this time I can't seem to get the darn thing to make the python implementation.

previously, I had to configure using the following command:

```
./configure --disable-openmp \
            --disable-dependency-tracking \
            CFLAGS="-arch i386 -arch x86_64 -O2" \
            CXXFLAGS="-arch i386 -arch x86_64 -O2"\
            --prefix=/usr/local\
            --with-python
```

but even with this, the post-configure message says:

```
##############################################
# Files will be installed in the following  ##
# directories:                              ##
##############################################

  Executables:        /usr/local/bin
  Libraries:          /usr/local/lib
  Header files:       /usr/local/include
  Extra Data:         /usr/local/share
  Man pages:          /usr/local/share/man
  Documentation:      /usr/local/share/doc/ViennaRNA
    (HTML):           /usr/local/share/doc/ViennaRNA/html
    (PDF):            /usr/local/share/doc/ViennaRNA
  Perl5 Interface:    
    (binaries):       /usr/local/Library/Perl/5.18/darwin-thread-multi-2level
    (scripts):        /usr/local/Library/Perl/5.18
  Python2 Interface:  Not to be installed
    (binaries):       
    (scripts):        
  Python3 Interface:  Not to be installed
    (binaries):       
    (scripts):
```

I went ahead and did `make` and `make install`. The program is installed (e.g. I can start it up when I type in `RNAfold` into the terminal window), however I can't seem to find the python implementation anywhere. After making, there are a few files in the "interfaces" folder named *RNA.py* and *RNA_wrap.cpp* (which was produced with [SWIG](http://www.swig.org/)). However, I can't seem to get these to run even if I start a python shell in that folder and type `import RNA`

Sorry I can't be of more use. Please let me know if you need more information about this particular situation. I'm running a late 2011 macbook pro and OSX el-capitan.

THANKS!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if you solved this problem yet or not, but I figured it out.

After opening the .gz folder, opening the terminal, and then setting the working directory to the root of the Vienna-2.3.1 package, you should run:

```
./configure --enable-macosx-installer
make
sudo make install
```

and then run the command "make check" to see if any compilations that you ran failed.

Then, what I did in order to get the RNA module to function was I first went to my Python IDE, changed my working directory to the Python folder in the interfaces folder, and then opened one of the example Python scripts (from the Examples folder). Then, I ran the example script, and my RNA module just started working.

Let me know if that's how you got it to work or not.

Edit: http://www.tbi.univie.ac.at/RNA/#self_packages

If you scroll down to the link provided, it has an already compiled binary package for Mac OS X. So that might also help.

Answer (score 1):

I just saw this post. You probably figure it out, but you what you need to do is to specify what version of python you want to be installed when you run /.configure. For example in my case, /.configure--with-python3